# SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Operation timed out. mysql does not work in Mac OS it seems not to start

Tags: php, mysql, macos, mysql-5.7

I tried to introduce larval and sql.

```
sudo php artisan serve
```

following errors happened.

Where should I look into and fix it?

Sequel ace can connect to mysql somehow.

.env

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=test
DB_USERNAME=laravel
DB_PASSWORD=laravel
```

```
: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Operation timed out

  at /Users/st/Developments/www/gg/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Driver/PDOConnection.php:31
    27|             parent::__construct($dsn, (string) $user, (string) $password, (array) $options);
    28|             $this->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_STATEMENT_CLASS, [PDOStatement::class, []]);
    29|             $this->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    30|         } catch (\PDOException $exception) {
  > 31|             throw new PDOException($exception);
    32|         }
    33|     }
    34| 
    35|     /**

  Exception trace:

  1   Illuminate\Foundation\Application::Illuminate\Foundation\{closure}(Object(App\Providers\AppServiceProvider))
      [internal]:0

  2   PDOException::("SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Operation timed out")
      /Users/st/Developments/www/gg/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Driver/PDOConnection.php:27
```

```
% mysql.server start             
Starting MySQL
.................................................................................................... 
ERROR! The server quit without updating PID file (/opt/homebrew/var/mysql/MacBook.local.pid).
```

I did this.

```
% touch /opt/homebrew/var/mysql/MacBook.local.pid
```

But nothing changed.

```
% sudo mysql -u root
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (38)
```

checked /tmp/
permissions mysql.sock are allowed for all users.

```
/tmp % ls -l                    
total 16
drwx------  3 stack  wheel   96  4 14 21:46 com.apple.launchd.4YE2dt8u
drwxr-xr-x@ 4 stack  wheel  128  4 14 21:46 com.google.Keystone
-rw-------  1 root     wheel   36  4 14 21:46 fseventsd-uuid
-rwxrwxrwx  1 root     wheel    0  4 17 21:37 mysql.sock
-rwxrwxrwx  1 stack  wheel    6  4 16 18:40 mysql.sock.lock
```

Comment: DId you try this?
sudo chown -R _mysql:_mysql  /opt/homebrew/var/mysql/MacBook.local.pid

Comment: I did it. but nothing changed.